# Manipulate SSIS Package Using XmlDocument

Tags: c#, ssis, xmldocument

I'm downgrading a SSIS package from 2014 to 2012. This processneeds to some search/replace and I know to do that manually. 
Now I'm trying to write a C# program to do the job.

This is the XML in `.DTSX` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DTS:Executable xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts"
  DTS:refId="Package"
  DTS:CreationDate="8/10/2016 11:39:29 AM"
  DTS:CreationName="Microsoft.Package"
  DTS:CreatorComputerName="FD89D67CEC21F"
  DTS:CreatorName="CORP\ZKHEKRZ"
  DTS:DTSID="{63B7F2FE-2D47-4710-82DF-83C92B7010B5}"
  DTS:ExecutableType="Microsoft.Package"
  DTS:LastModifiedProductVersion="12.0.4100.1"
  DTS:LocaleID="1033"
  DTS:ObjectName="CubeDailyBackup"
  DTS:PackageType="5"
  DTS:VersionBuild="131"
  DTS:VersionGUID="{8F0EAFC9-D73C-463C-8D5E-CB33C858D0D5}">
  <DTS:Property DTS:Name="PackageFormatVersion">8</DTS:Property>
  ....... more lines below
```

At first step I need to replace

```
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="PackageFormatVersion">8</DTS:Property>
```

with

```
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="PackageFormatVersion">6</DTS:Property>
```

To do the job, I load `.DTSX` file using `XmlDocument` and then find the node using below code

```
private XmlDocument Pkg14 = new XmlDocument();
Pkg14.Load("mypackage.dtsx");
XmlNodeList xnList = Pkg14.SelectNodes("//DTS:Property[@DTS:Name='PackageFormatVersion']");
```

Executing the third line throws below error:

> Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix,
>   variable, or user-defined function

Please advise.

**EDIT:**

I tried adding below code before Pkg14.SelectNodex but it did not help:

```
    XmlNamespaceManager xmlnsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(Pkg14.NameTable);
    xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("DTS", "www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dts/tasks/webservicetask");
    ..... and adding more namespace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the correct URL mapped to the prefix (`DTS` prefix in your code mapped to a different URI from the one in your XML). Also make sure you pass the `XmlNamespaceManager` along with the XPath query to `SelectNodes()` or `SelectSingleNode()` method :

```
Pkg14.Load("mypackage.dtsx");

XmlNamespaceManager xmlnsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(Pkg14.NameTable);
xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("DTS", "www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts");

XmlNode node = Pkg14.SelectSingleNode("//DTS:Property[@DTS:Name='PackageFormatVersion']", xmlnsManager);
node.InnerText = "6";

//save the modified XmlDocument back to file
Pkg14.Save("mypackage.dtsx");
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q92tYf)</kbd>**

Comment: Thank you for answer! I need one more hint. I'm going to have plenty of "SelectNodes", how I can avoid passing the xmlnsManager for every single call? I tried to set xmlnsManager to Pkg14.XmlResolver but got compile error. Any idea?